# read txt files with left-aligned data but inconsistent number of spaces in R

Tags: r, file, load, spaces, right-align

I have a series of txt files formatted in the same way.
The first few rows are all about file information. There are no variable names. As you can see spaces between factors are inconsistent but Columns are left-aligned or right-aligned.I know SAS could directly read data with this format and wonder if R provide any function similar.

I tried read.csv function to load these data and I want to save them in a data.frame with 3 columns, while it turns out the option sep = "\s"(multiple spaces) in the function cannot recognize regular expression.

So I tried to read these data in a variable first and use substr function to split them as following. 
step1

```
 Factor<-data.frame(substr(Share$V1,1,9),substr(Share$V1,9,14),as.numeric(substr(Share$V1,15,30)))
```

step2

But this is quite unintelligent, and need to count the spaces between.
I wander if there is any method to directly load data as three columns.

```
    > Factor
   F  T      S
1   +B2P       A     1005757219
2   +BETA      A      826083789
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `read.table` to read it as 3 columns

```
read.table(text=as.character(Share$V1), sep="", header=FALSE, 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE, col.names = c("FactorName", "Type", "Share"))
#  FactorName Type      Share
#1       +B2P    A 1005757219
#2      +BETA    A  826083789
#3       +E2P    A  499237181
#4      +EF2P    A   38647147
#5     +EFCHG    A  866171133
#6    +IL1QNS    A  945726018
#7    +INDMOM    A  862690708
```

---

Another option would be to read it directly from the file, `skip`ping the header line and change the column names

```
read.table("yourfile.txt", header=FALSE, skip=1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
              col.names = c("FactorName", "Type", "Share"))
```

Comment: I see where I coded  wrong. The default argument sep = ""(no space) refers to one or more spaces, but I typed sep = " "(one space) which lead to exact match and incorrectly split. the columns.Thus function read.csv also work for this problem.